# How to make folders in a list directory display as a button and the files as a downloadable link?

Tags: php

I am working on a file management system that lists my directories and files. I need to be able to make the directories and subdirectories a button and the files a href downloadable link. The issue I am having is that when I check the list to see if a file exist it changes all of the list items into a downloadable link instead of just the file.

Here is a section of my code that is used to output the table with the file and folder names from my directory. The way that this is set up is that it will either display the button if the file does not exist or display the href to download if a file exist. it is outputting the href for the folders and files instead of just the files. How can I get it to output a button if its a directory or subdirectory and make the files an href for download?

```
            if (file_exists($_POST["folder_name"])) {

                                    $output .='

        <tr>

        <td><a href ='.$path. ' download  id ="subfolder" data-name="'.$file['name'].'">' .basename($file['name']). '</a></td>
        <td>'.date('M j Y g:i A', $file['lastmod']).'</td>
        <td><button type="button" name="delete" data-name="'.$file['name'].'" class="delete btn btn-warning btn-xs">Delete</button></td>
        <td><button type="button" name="upload" data-name="'.$file['name'].'" class="upload btn btn-warning btn-xs">Upload</button></td>
        </tr>';       
            }
```

Comment: Use [is_dir()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php) maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Use is_dir() to see if item is a directory. Also, make sure that you actually mean $_POST, because that comes from the user, not from the file system. Elsewhere in your script, you use $file.

```
if(is_dir($_POST["folder_name"])) {
  $output .=' ... folder html ... ';
} else {
  $output .=' ... file html ... ';
}
```

Assuming that the user passes the folder name in $_POST, you might have something like this:

```
foreach(scandir($_POST['folder_name']) as $file) 
{
    if(is_dir($file)) {
      $output .=' ... folder html ... ';
    } else {
      $output .=' ... file html ... ';
    }
}
```

Also note that this is a huge security issue because you allow the user to specify an arbitrary folder on your filesystem.

Comment: I am using $_POST for my user action. I am loading the directory on ready and then when the user clicks the directory button I send the user into the directory and the table updates based on the users action. I have used $is_dir, the problem is that I have files and subdirectories in my directories so when $is_dir or $file_exists is true it makes my table a button when I need the directories and subdirectories to be buttons and the files to be href so the user can download the file when the file is clicked or go further into the directory when a folder is clicked.

Comment: @ZacharyTaylor it is really unclear what you are going on about here. Please edit your question to include the code where you are actually reading the directory contents. _“when I need the directories and subdirectories to be buttons and the files to be href”_ - so, check for each individual directory entry that you output, whether it is a file or a directory - what is the problem with that?